# I am getting an Epipe error while trying to deploy AWS ECS cluster with a docker image where all of them areexposed to port 80

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, fly

## the error:

ecs-stack-dev: deploying... [1/1]
18:45:43
[0%] start: Building and publishing 4ec4aa06fxxxx:current

18:45:43
events.js:377

18:45:43
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

18:45:43
^
18:45:43

18:45:43
Error: write EPIPE

18:45:43
at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:156:25)

18:45:43
at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:147:3)

18:45:43
at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:798:11)

18:45:43
at Socket._write (net.js:810:8)

18:45:43
at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)

18:45:43
at Socket.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)

18:45:43
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:266:55500

18:45:43
at new Promise ()

18:45:43
at shell (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:266:5
5437)
18:45:43
at Docker.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:266:59396)

18:45:43
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:

18:45:43
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)

18:45:43
at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)

18:45:43
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
{
18:45:43
errno: -32,

18:45:43
code: 'EPIPE',

18:45:43
syscall: 'write'

18:45:43
}

## the code:

```
import aws_cdk.aws_ecs as ecs
import aws_cdk.aws_s3 as s3
import aws_cdk.aws_ec2 as ec2
import aws_cdk.core as core
import aws_cdk.aws_iam as iam
import aws_cdk.aws_ecs_patterns as ecs_patterns

class EcsStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, vpc: ec2.Vpc, id: str,  STAGE: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id)

        # Create an ECS cluster
        self.ecs_cluster = ecs.Cluster(self, "ngnix-cluster",
                                       cluster_name="ngnix-cluster",
                                       vpc=vpc)

        self.ECSTaskExecRole = iam.Role(self, "ECSTaskExecRole",
            description="IAM Role for ECS",
            role_name=f'ECS-Role-{STAGE}',
            assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal("ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"))

        self.ECSTaskExecRole.add_managed_policy(iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name("service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"))

        self.ECSTaskExecRole.add_to_policy(iam.PolicyStatement(
            actions=[
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage"],
            resources=['*'],
            effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW))

        self.ECSTaskExecRole.add_to_policy(iam.PolicyStatement(
            actions=[
                'kms:Decrypt',
                'kms:DescribeKey',
                'kms:Encrypt',
                'kms:ReEncrypt*',
                'kms:CreateGrant',
                'kms:ListGrants',
                'kms:RevokeGrant',
                'kms:GenerateDataKey*',
                'secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy',
                'secretsmanager:GetSecretValue',
                'secretsmanager:DescribeSecret',
                'secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds'],
            resources=['*'],
            effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW))

        # Create a task definition
        self.ECS_Task_Definition = ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(self, "Fargate Task Definition",
            execution_role=self.ECSTaskExecRole,
            task_role=self.ECSTaskExecRole)

        # Add a container to the task definition
        self.ECS_Task_Definition.add_container("nginx-container", 
                                               container_name='ngnix-config',
                                               image=ecs.ContainerImage.from_asset("./docker/docker_ecs"),
                                               port_mappings=[ecs.PortMapping(container_port=80, host_port=80)],)

        # Create a Fargate service using the task definition and cluster
        ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
            self, "MyECSService",
            cluster=self.ecs_cluster,
            task_definition=self.ECS_Task_Definition,
            platform_version=ecs.FargatePlatformVersion.VERSION1_4,
            desired_count=2,
            listener_port=80,
            open_listener=True)
```

Comment: Could you describe what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I sam treying to run `ECS with a provided Docker image thsts all